# JSON Syntax and Code for uploading files to ContentDocument object

Tags: java, json, salesforce

I'm working on creating a application to import files (currently .pdf only) from a shared folder to a Salesforce environment. I found the Salesforce documentation for the JSON synax and code needed to import a Document object but for whatever reason the people who initially set up the Salesforce instance only uploaded files before as ContentDocument objects, not Document objects.

Is there a standard JSON code format for uploading a .pdf directly to ContentDocument objects directly. All my search queries lead me to Data Loader which doesn't seem to match with the task I've been given.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm

Answer (score 0):

`ContentDocument` records cannot be created directly. Rather, you create a `ContentVersion` record over the API, and Salesforce automatically creates the `ContentDocument`, or adds the version to an existing one if you populate the `ContentDocumentId` field

The document you're looking at is the right one as far as where this is documented, it just doesn't provide an explicit example of how to upload without using multipart messages. So long as you stay under the limit

> You can insert or update blob data using a non-multipart message, but you are limited to 50 MB of text data or 37.5 MB of base64–encoded data.

you can do this with a non-multipart JSON request.

You'd do a POST request to

```
<your instance URL>/services/data/v46.0/sobjects/ContentVersion
```

with the JSON body

```
{
    "PathOnClient": <your file's name and extension>,
    "Title": <your desired title>,
    "VersionData": <base64-encoded file contents
}
```

If you want to share the file directly with a record, populate the record Id in `FirstPublishLocationId`. (This works only with *new* documents; you cannot add a new version to an existing document and share it this way).

That's (mostly) it! The only other piece you might need to do is query the created record back from Salesforce to get its associated `ContentDocumentId` if you need to do more sharing work.